# Swift 2.2: How can I append to an existing Set?

Tags: swift2

I want to exploit the properties of a Set but I don't see any way to append to an existing Set.

Here's what I have:

```
var mySet = Set<Int>()
```

I would like to do something like:

```
mySet.append(8)
```

...which isn't possible.

How can I add to a Set?

Comment: Read the documentation for Set and see the list of instance methods? I also just made a Google search with "swift set append" and the solution is in the first answers... which are reflecting the documentation.

Comment: I found the 'insert' command; which would work.

Answer (score 19):

I discovered the 'insert' command; which is adequate.